# Can I use 2 if statements in a while loop?

Tags: javascript

I try to get Found (name) grade is (grade) but seems like the code only work for the first person which is Bob, but when it is George, it said not found.

```
var studentArray = [
  { 'name': 'Bob', 'grade': 87 },
  { 'name': 'Fred', 'grade': 82 },
  { 'name': 'George', 'grade': 93 },
  { 'name': 'Robert', 'grade': 85 }
];

function findStudent(studentName) {
  var i = 0; //var i = 0 should be inside
  var output = "";

  while (i < studentArray.length) {
    if(studentName === studentArray[i].name) {
      output = ( "Found " + studentName + " their grade is " + studentArray[i]['grade']);
    } else {
      output = ("Student " + studentName + " not found.");
    }
    i++;
  }

  return output;
}

var name = 'George';
var result = findStudent(name);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: well you can only say not found after you looked at all of them.... so it has to happen outside the loop. You really should use modern technique with `find()`

Comment: you should be returning as soon as one is found....or the whole loop completes and only the last item will matter

Comment: *seems like the code only work for the first person* - that is unlikely, it should work for the last person. You overwrite `output` in each iteration, so at the end it will say something about the last item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the check outside the loop

```js
var studentArray = [{ 'name': 'Bob', 'grade': 87 }, { 'name': 'Fred', 'grade': 82 }, { 'name': 'George', 'grade': 93 }, { 'name': 'Robert', 'grade': 85 }]


function findStudent(studentName) {
  var i = 0;
  var output = "";
  while (i < studentArray.length) {
    if (studentName === studentArray[i].name) {
      output = ("Found " + studentName + " their grade is " + studentArray[i]['grade']);
    }
    i++;
  }
  
  if (!output) {
    output = ("Student " + studentName + " not found.");
  }

  return output;
}
var name = 'George';
var result = findStudent(name);
console.log(result);
```

Most people would use find()

```js
var studentArray = [{ 'name': 'Bob', 'grade': 87 }, { 'name': 'Fred', 'grade': 82 }, { 'name': 'George', 'grade': 93 }, { 'name': 'Robert', 'grade': 85 }]


function findStudent(studentName) {
  var out = studentArray
    .find(function (o) { 
      return o.name===studentName; 
    });
  return out
    ? `Found ${studentName} their grade is ${out.grade}` 
    : `Student ${studentName} not found.`
}
var name = 'George';
var result = findStudent(name);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Found, you should immediately return, and not go through the whole loop